# Google Maps Authencification Error ( Android Studio )

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I started developing an application with Google Maps and I struggled to execute code after add. The first run I run perfectly from Genymotion emulator, but testing on mobile skips the following error, and the mobile device does not display the map.
The key is added properly and the API also.

Any suggestions?

[image: Error Android Studio here]

[image: Apis habilitadas]

I hope you can answer.

Comment: Already it solved a couple of weeks ago, thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add your API KEY from google in your **AndroidManifest.xml**.

```
<application>
[...]
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"      android:value="YOUR_KEY_HERE"/>
[...]
</application>
```

replace  "YOUR_KEY_HERE" with the actual key provided by google.

Follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#get_an_android_api_key) to generate such key.